# Near Maximum Distance Separable Code

Tags: finite-field, coding-theory, mds

I want to find the minimum distance of an $[8,4]$ Near MDS code over a finite field F_4 (NMDS Code is a type of linear code). I want to know which programming language has a built-in function that will return the minimum distance (or the minimum weight) of this code.

Answer (score 1):

This is on topic: Near MDS codes are said to have applications in combinatorics and cryptography.

Near MDS codes are "almost MDS" in parameters and MDS codes are directly related to orthogonal arrays which have applications in cryptography (e.g., to resilient functions). An MDS code has the largest possible minimum distance for a given length $n$ and dimension $k$, namely $d=n-k+1.$

A code is near MDS if both itself and its dual are almost MDS, i.e., with parameters $[n,k,d=n-k]$ over whatever finite field. The paper "Near MDS Codes from oval polynomials" partially available [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0012365X20304635#:%7E:text=A%20code%20is%20said%20to,applications%20in%20combinatorics%20and%20cryptography.) constructs some such codes.

Therefore an $[n=8,k=4]$ near MDS code has a minimum distance $d=n-k=4.$ For this you don't need a package. But you may want to construct the code itself.

MDS codes such as Reed-Solomon codes can be constructed from polynomials. This can be done in various software packages. I am most familiar with Magma, which has a freely available online calculator [here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/). See the Chapter on Coding Theory on the Handbook link at the calculator site.

**Edit:** Comments mentioned sagemath.cell as well as Python as possible alternatives. I also know that the public domain pari/gp package does the same things as magma.

Comment: Well, SagaMath.Cell beats Magma...

Comment: Sagemath? May well do.

Comment: How about Python? Is that good for Galois fields and NMDS codes?

Comment: I don't know if there are libraries available in Python--sorry, others might know.